# Run a node command in Nightwatch global after

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I would like to run a nodemailer js file in the 'after' global for my nightwatch testing suite. Here is the command I run now to fire off a sample test and have it use 'nightwatch-html-reporter' to generate an html report.

```
node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --config nightwatch.conf.BASIC.js --test test\e2e\search.js --reporter ./reports/reporter.js
```

The idea is, after this report is run and created, I want to email it right away.

This is the command I use in powershell right after the above one to email the report using 'nodemailer' and 'nodemailer-sendgrid-transport'

```
node reports/nodemailer.js
```

I tried merging the code from nodemailer.js into the reporter.js file but it interferes with the creation of the report. How do I get this to email automagically after the report is generated.

Is there a way in my globals.js file to trigger this node command in the 'after' command like this?:

```
module.exports = {
// this controls whether to abort the test execution when an assertion failed and skip the rest
// it's being used in waitFor commands and expect assertions
abortOnAssertionFailure: true,

... 

'default': {
    myGlobal: function () {
        return 'I\'m a method';
    }
},

'emailReport': { <-- HERE???
    myGlobal: function () {
         node reports/nodemailer.js <--???
    }
},

...

after(cb) {
    this.emailReport.myGlobal(); <---???
    cb();
},
afterEach(browser, cb) {
    browser.perform(function () {
        //console.log('GLOBAL afterEach')
        cb();
    });
},

reporter(results, cb) { <-- or in here somehow???
    cb();
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I needed to put all the code into the global.js directly in the 'after' command like this:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
// this controls whether to abort the test execution when an assertion failed and skip the rest
// it's being used in waitFor commands and expect assertions
abortOnAssertionFailure: true,
...

'default': {
    myGlobal: function () {
        return 'I\'m a method';
    }
},

'test_env': {
    myGlobal: 'test_global',
    beforeEach: function () {

    }
},

before(cb) {
    //console.log('GLOBAL BEFORE')
    cb();
},

beforeEach(browser, cb) {
    //console.log('GLOBAL beforeEach')
    browser.maximizeWindow();
    cb();
},

after(cb) {
    // send email with generated report
    var file;
    if (fs.existsSync('./reports/html/report.html')) {
        file = fs.readFileSync('./reports/html/report.html', "utf8");
    }
    var client = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'SendGrid',
        auth: {
            user: 'USERNAME',
            pass: 'PASSWORDAPIKEY'
        }
    });

    var email = {
        from: 'user@domain.com',
        to: 'user@domain.com',
        subject: 'Nightwatch Report',
        //text: 'Hello world',
        html: file
    };

    client.sendMail(email, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
    cb();
},

afterEach(browser, cb) {
    browser.perform(function () {
        //console.log('GLOBAL afterEach')
        cb();
    });
},

reporter(results, cb) {
    cb();
}
```

};